# Teams proactive messages and Graph API token

Tags: javascript, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to build a bot that sends proactive user recommendations regularly. They look similar to this one: [image]

I have it all working in terms of user data coming from the backend, but I also want to add some additional things coming from the Graph API - one of which is the profile picture.

I've setup an Azure Bot Channel, got the [Graph auth sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) running, but I still can't figure how to mix the proactive messages with the OAuthPrompt dialog.

If I make the user sign in upon app registration, can I reliably get the graph token and use it in my proactive message handler? Note that these messages are going to be sent on a weekly basis. I'm afraid that the token is going to expire.

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: What exactly are you using Graph for? You should be able to send proactive messages without making any calls to Graph. And if you do need to call Graph, you can authorize your bot (via App Registrations) to make those calls for any user so you wouldn't need a user specific token.

Comment: @billoverton I'd need the Graph to take the profile picture of the suggested user before sending it in the chat. Could you link any documentation for using the Graph API without an user specific token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the bot to make a call to Graph and retrieve user data, you can use Application Permissions to do this without having the user log in. First, you will need to enable the permissions in Azure Active Directory>App registrations>API permissions. The particular ones you need here is `User.Read.All` (or `User.ReadWrite.All` if you might want it to have write access for other use cases). There are also separate permissions for Group and Contact if you need that.

For the bot, you first need to get the token. There's a whole reference article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) (which includes the app permissions as described above). The client ID and secret are the values for your application. So in javascript I do something like

```js
        var identityUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
        var formData = `client_id=${clientId}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=${clientSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials`
        try {
            var idResponse = await request({
                url: identityUrl,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'},
                form: formData
            });
            var token = JSON.parse(idResponse).access_token;
        } catch (err) {
            await step.context.sendActivity(`Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.`);
            console.log(err.message);
            return step.endDialog();
        }
```

I've got a lot going on where I'm making an actual call to graph, but my http call looks like this:

```js
            var userResponse = await request({
                url: usersUrl + queryString,
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`, 'ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}
            });
            userResponse = JSON.parse(userResponse);
```

Now in your case you're calling the Get Photo endpoint, which I haven't done, but should be basically the same as the above. Here is a link for the [Get photo documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0). So now, you bot should be able to authenticate and grab the picture before sending the proactive message, without any need for the user to ever give any credentials.